# Translation of "To seek joy and meaning in life"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I have survived a very difficult period in my life and want to mark my survival with a latin phrase meaning "To seek joy and meaning in my life". Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: When you say 'to seek', do you mean that as a plain infinitive or as a purpose clause ("I got this tattoo to seek (~to remind me to seek?) joy and meaning in my life")?